# Is there a way to identify if a custom machine type is N1 or N2 on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm working to identify if a machine type is N1, N2 or E2 on GCE, but I can't identify this if the machine type is custom

Ex: custom (6 vCPUs, 10 GB memory) vs n1-standard-2 (2 vCPUs, 7.5 GB memory)

Is there a way to get to know this?

Comment: What OS? How do you want to access this information (CLI, programming language, etc). Have you looked at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/describe which provides details https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get https://www.tecmint.com/check-linux-cpu-information/

Comment: Linux, I tried through CLI (gcloud) and GUI. I'm able but on machineType I only get "custom-6-10240"

https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project/zones/zone/machineTypes/custom-6-10240

Comment: And that is not the information you are looking for?

Comment: The N1, N2 machine types are names given by GCP to pre-built machine types. If a user customizes their machine type, then it will be marked as "custom".

Answer (score 3):

A virtual machine can be mapped on three main parameters. your CPU core, RAM and processor(and yes of course on the brand ie. intel) in GHz. 
To map and existing custom machine type, you would need to compare all these parameters.
You can find more detail about each machine type and it's speed here [N1D machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the CPU platform:

- Intel Skylake for N1
- Intel Cascade Lake for N2